# Error on Signed APK

Tags: apk, signed

i'm having error in my signed apk. I was able to make a signed apk in my other project but this one the signed apk will prompt an error once runned in phone. I can't seem to find the cause since its already signed and theres no log in the logcat of intellij.

The last time I did was I change the file name of the output apk(ex. from test.apk to mytest.apk) but when I installed it and run its not working, with error "Unfortunetly mytest app is not working."Is there something wrong with the package if we change the name?

Other thing is, is there a way to locate logs error in signed apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see the logs in the emulator. access your emulator through adb -s  shell.
if your already inside the emulator just type logcat and it will print the logs of the emulator. you will see lots of text so you might need to add spaces to separate your latest logs, just hit enter. then in your emulator try to run the application that you want to see the logs and it will print.

Comment: Wow, thanks I just tried it. It shows all my error logs history. Now I can see that I my package is the problem.

Comment: you could also use this command if you want to see only the logs of the package. logcat -d |grep 'name_of_package'

Comment: yes, it does too. thanks buddy, great help for a newbie like me.